# Is there an integral transform formula for $(-\nabla^2 + m^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ in three dimensions? What about its one sided inverse?

Tags: laplacian, integral-transforms, fractional-calculus

I have come across the following formula for the positive square root of the (negative) 3D Laplacian

$$(-\nabla^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}[u](y) = C \text{ p.v. }\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\frac{u(y)-u(x)}{\|y-x\|^4}dx$$

as well as the one-sided inverse of this operator:

$$(-\nabla^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}[u](y) = D\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\frac{u(x)}{\|y-x\|^2}dx$$.

Are there analogous formulas for the operator $$(-\nabla^2 +m^2 )^{\frac{1}{2}}$$ where m is a real number?

Comment: See https://handwiki.org/wiki/Screened_Poisson_equation It solves the problem for the operator $(-\nabla^2+m^2)$. But the same procedure (see "The Green's function in r is therefore given by the inverse Fourier transform") can be used to compute the integral representation for this case also. The problem reduces to evaluating the Fourier integral $\int \frac{k\sin(kx)}{\sqrt{k^2+m^2}}dk$